# Install Play 1.7.1 on Windows

Tags: playframework

I've downloaded in C:\soft...

- Java 8 (jdk-1.8.401)
- Python (python-3.12.2-amd64)
- git (v2)
- play (play-1.7.1 imposed version)

I work on Windows (because of the migration that I have to do, of an old application).

When I execute on git

```
$ play
```

This error appears :

```
/c/soft/play/play: line 5: from: command not found
/c/soft/play/play: line 6: import: command not found
/c/soft/play/play: line 7: import: command not found
/c/soft/play/play: line 8: import: command not found
/c/soft/play/play: line 9: import: command not found
/c/soft/play/play: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `os.path.join'
/c/soft/play/play: line 11: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])), 'framework', 'pym'))'
```

which corresponds to

```
 1
 2  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 3  # Play command line script www.playframework.com/
 4  
 5  from __future__ import print_function
 6  import sys
 7  import os
 8  import os.path
 9  import re
10
11  sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])), 'framework', 'pym'))
12  
13  from play.cmdloader import CommandLoader
14  from play.application import PlayApplication
15  from play.utils import *
```

When I run play in a simple terminal, I get the error on another .py file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\soft\play\play", line 13, in <module>
     from play.cmdloader import CommandLoader
   File "C:\soft\play\framework\pym\play\cmdloader.py", line 2, in <module>
     imp import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
```

So, it's seems to be a python problem. But what can I do if the .py files don't exist in the .zip distribution I download from the site?

This is not surprising since none of these commands are found in play\framework\pym\play\commands. But then how do I use command line project creation if the basic play script doesn't work?

Thank's for your help.

I tried with different versions of the different elements and tried to follow the installation process from the play framework installation guide.
I'd like to know if I missed a step in the installation process.

Comment: That code looks like Python. Have you tried using Python to run it?

Comment: Yes, this is the case: this play file is launched with python in the Windows play.bat file:
`
@echo off
"python" "%~dp0play" %*
`

Comment: The last error message points to line 2 in *cmdloader.py*. You need to look in that file to see what is wrong. Also the first set of error messages do not look like actual Python errrors.

Comment: Yes, you are right: the error on line 2 is a call to the imp.py file which does not exist. But imp is used in the rest of the play.py file ( imp.load_source(...), imp.find_module(...), imp.load_module(...)).
- Why would this file contain errors?
- Why does the called file not exist?
- Other files called do not exist and that does not seem to pose a problem. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: This looks like it is an issue with the *play* package that you are trying to use.

Comment: Yes, it seems.
But the script plays looks identical regardless of the version.

Answer (score 0):

It's like versions 1.7 (1.7.0 and 1.7.1) don't work for Windows (I know 1.7.1 works on Linux).
I took play version 1.6.0 and was able to generate a new project.

Comment: And it wasn't just a question of Java version (java 8 for play version 1.6, java 11 for play version 1.7).